# "Find All References" across files for a method/function in VSCode is not possible

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code version `1.27.2`

`Find all References` only list references in the `current file`.
I need to find all references across files in a project.

Is it possible ?

Something like `find usages`

If you right click a `symbol` and select "find usages". If the current symbol is a `function`, then "find usages" searches for all places where this function is called. If the current symbol is a `variable`, then "find usages" searches for all places where this variable is used etc etc.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: @MattBierner javascript and ruby

Comment: @Mark what you are saying is Search!. I meant some functionality which most of the editors has including Sublime, RubyMine, and others (go to declaration, go to definitions, find all usages)

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, a colleague of mine found a directory Code under directory ~/.config. I delete it without more cautions ... lost some history like recent files or projects but my Intellisense is working correctly again

Comment: Is there any script that can list down all the files which are having the reference of a given file?

Comment: I dont think this works in VS Code (mac). As the original post says, the search only occurs in the current file but not in the entire repo (folder), within other files.

Answer (score 40):

Advanced features such as `Find all references` are implemented by each language extension.

For JavaScript, try creating a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) at the root of your workspace with the contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

This file tells VS Code to treat all JS files in your workspace as part of the same javascript project. `Find all references` still may not work properly in JavaScript if your code is too dynamic. It works best against modern js that uses `import`/`export`, `class`, and friends

Comment: I need need exactly this feature, too - other IDEs (qt-creator, clion) provide this for c++ symbols

Comment: Docs for this feature: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: According to the latest Vscode docs 
 the options from Jsconfig are no longer respected. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

Comment: @joseph Is there any workaround now? if I want VSCode to find references across closed files?

Comment: @eliezra236 have you tried the solution in this Stack Overflow answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184790/how-to-using-vscode-javascripts-go-to-definition-cross-files

Comment: I'm using Typescript. For me I needed to add a tsconfig.json file and follow enable the extension from @FlakDiNenno comment. All G now

Answer (score 27):

In Visual Studio Code you can do this by first highlighting the text you want to search for, then using the command: CTRL + SHIFT + F (pressing all at once).

CTRL + SHIFT + F is just a shortcut for accessing the search tab on the left-hand side of VSCode. Hope that helps and apologies for the scribbles :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so it's more like  a textual search than a semantic one .. Is there one anything that actually will take the language (say C++) into account?

Comment: this is the only right answer you should maybe update it with CMD+SHFT+F for mac users..

Comment: `Find in Files` is different from `Find All references`, the former being text based lexer type thing, the latter is actually language semantics as far as I know, probably driven by libclang at this point of tooling. See the sidebar, find in files uses the magnifying glass, find all references uses the second to the bottom icon, that page pointing to a page thing.

Comment: This is not ideal becuase, It is looking for the TEXT instead of the actual REFERENCE of the function.

Answer (score 6):

Right-click on the variable and choose `Find All References`
[This is how it looks in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8csNa.jpg)

My `About Visual Studio Code Info`:

```
Version: 1.47.2
Commit: 17299e413d5590b14ab0340ea477cdd86ff13daf
Date: 2020-07-15T18:18:50.054Z (5 days ago)
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.6.0
```

Comment: This is what I want, but what I get is just the references in that specific file.  I'm using Angular/Typescript

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter/Dart user, this should be fixed in dart `3.1.0-155.0.dev`.

See https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4535

Answer (score 0):

[VS Code's builtin support for different programming/other languages](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions) does not cover every language under the sun, and the degree to which is supports those languages varies. The design of VS Code is so that it can be extended (For example, see [the `ReferenceProvider` part of the extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ReferenceProvider)). So there are a couple of possibilities:

- You need to install an extension that provides "Find All References" using [VS Code's extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api). Search [the extension marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) and try to find one.
- No such lanugage-support extension exists which provides references support, in which case you either need to wait for it to be created, or the support to be added to an existing language-support extension, or make it happen yourself (write that extension or contribute that feature to an existing extension).
- A language-support extension exists which provides references support and you have installed it, but more configuration information is needed for the extension to be able to understand your environment and project setup. Ex.

  - VS Code's builtin JavaScript and TypeScript language support may require you to help it understand the shape of your project (see [related docs for JS usage](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson)) if the layout is less conventional.
  - The C/C++ extension (Cpptools) may require configuration of IntelliSense (see [related docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-get-intellisense-to-work-correctly)).
- A language-support extension exists which provides references support and you have installed it and set it up properly, but the support is partial/incomplete, or has buggy behaviour, or behaves sensibly, but different than how you'd personally like it to behave- in which case, either ask the extension maintainer nicely to fix the bug / implement the feature / provide configurability. Make sure you search first to see if such a bug/feature has been already raised, and consider going an extra mile to contribute the change yourself. Ex.

  - For the C/C++ extension (Cpptools), see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/labels/Feature%3A%20Find%20All%20References.
  - For VS Code's builtin JavaScript/TypeScript support, you probably should look in the issue tracker for TypeScript itself, since that's what VS Code's language support for JS and TS is built on- TypeScript itself does most of the "heavy lifting".

---

Sometimes, you can work around the missing feature by just doing a textual search. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files. Though I'd expect that to break down if you care about references in dependencies whose files are not located inside your currently open workspace. See also the `search.exclude` and `files.exclude` settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `clangd` plugin for clang languages like C/C++ etc.**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd

That plugin is simply amazing, it works across files and fast, I've covered its setup at: [VSCode "go to definition" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341849/vscode-go-to-definition-not-working/76193270#76193270) and it requires a [`compile_commads.json` database](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html), which e.g. CMake supports.

The general trade-off with the official C/C++ extension is that clangd tends to be more accurate, though generating the DB can be a bit slower, and requires a bit more configuration.

I just wish vscode had a "find only references that modify a variable" mode however: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/yx2uvk/find_all_references_equivalent_to_only_find/ (not clangd specific, the clangd backend might even support it I'm not sure)

**Quick benchmark on Git source**

Let's give this a try on Ubuntu 23.10, vscode 1.87.1, C/C++ extension v1.19.6, Lenovo ThinkPad P14s:

```
sudo apt install gettext libcurl4-openssl-dev cloc
sudo snap install --classic code
git clone https://github.com/git/git
cd git
git checkout e09f1254c54329773904fe25d7c545a1fb4fa920
make -j CC=clang GENERATE_COMPILATION_DATABASE=yes
code .
```

For magnitude:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                      files          blank        comment           code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C                               578          46079          39966         265796
```

so about 266 KLOC, and erm, it seems to work great, every definition I click opens quite fast, and so do references, including across files.

So there must have been some specific feature of another closed source project I've tested it on that prevented it from working well at all on it, perhaps a humongous .gitignored directory with lots of C code in it or maybe also a slow disk? Not sure.

Comment: do you have any benchmarks comparing with the cpptools extension? I know [they've done some recent performance work recently related to go-to-symbol](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11557), but I don't know about how performant their find-references is.

Comment: @starball I don't, I just compare informally to one experience with built-in thing which is hopeless for whatever reason, possibly due to going into large git ignored directories. C source is not humongous in the project in mind.

Comment: @starball I've added a test on the Git project and it worked, so the other closed source project I had in mind must have had other more complex issues that made things not work. Notably, I think it was looking into large .gitignore folders, but not 100% certain.

Comment: related settings for search include/exclude: `search.exclude`, `C_Cpp.files.exclude` (for cpptools).