# how to find 'Find All refernces' in current file only with visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when i hit Find All References it try to find all reference in files inside workspace.

i want to use current file only when search 'Find all reference' function in vs code.

[image]

i want to search only References in yellow marked file which is currently editing file and don't want to search files all other files like purple X marked area.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52711331/836330 looks like it is language extension-dependent.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the find feature with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> on mac)
2. Enter the search term and configure your desired case sensitivity/regex usage
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on mac)

All occurrences in the open file will be selected. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return focus to the editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can also select the text you'd like to find and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to jump to each reference of that text in the file!

Comment: Very nice!  It's "Command+D" on a mac

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>  will open search.
- Click on the 3 dots (Toggle search details) under search dialog box. [ ... ]
- Under `file to include`, specify the path of the file under which you want to find all the references to the key you're searching.

Comment: thanks for reply! i updated question . i added more picture for explain detail. thanks !