# Identify unused styles in useStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui

I just spend the last 10min trying to find out which styles I actually use in my component, and which ones are legacy. That brought me to the question, is there a better way? How do you keep them clean? I was looking for some kind of extension for Visual Studio Code (which I use) but wasn't able to find one.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  actions: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  buttons: { display: "flex" },
  connectLinkIcon: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.fontSize * 1.5,
  },
  connectButton: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  connectMenu: {
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[300]}`,
  },
  buttonIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  listItemIcon: {
    minWidth: 35,
  },
  profileInfo: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  profileInfoText: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  profileAvatar: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  profileName: {
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
  },
}));
```

Comment: the answer may depend on what IDE you use so you should provide that info

Comment: Oh yes of course. I use Visual Studio Code. Sorry, I forgot that part.

Comment: Visual Studio Code - Then obvious method is you can see the unused classes will be greyed out & on hovering it shows declared a value but it is never read , also by running the app and in browser console the unused classes will be shown

Comment: Hmm not sure if I am missing something then because `test` in my example here is not used as I just added it, but it's not greyed out and looks like its needed https://imgur.com/a/N06Hb82

Comment: It is only greyed out if the whole variable is not used. If you want to see if there is any references to that property, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677651/find-all-references-across-files-for-a-method-function-in-vscode-is-not-possib) will help you.