# VS code JS find references only work for the current file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using `Go to References` function on VS code on a JS file. It only finds references on the current file, where I would like to find all references across all the files in the project directly. I do not want to use `search all`, since I enjoy the little preview window that `Go to References` provides. With TS, `Go to References` finds for all files, but with JS, it seems to not work. Is there any fix to this to make `Go to References` work across all files for JS?

Here is a video showing the problem:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Find All References" across files for a method/function in VSCode is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677651/find-all-references-across-files-for-a-method-function-in-vscode-is-not-possib)

Comment: tried that, does not work